# Minimal sufficient statistic for simple correlated model

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, regression

Consider the simple linear correlation model $Y_i=\alpha+ \beta X_i+\epsilon_i \ ; 
 \ \ i=1,..n$. Here $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$
Here $X_1,X_2,...X_n \sim N(0,\tau^2)$(i.i.d) and $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$(i.i.d). Also, $X_i's$ are independent of $\epsilon_i's$ Find a minimal sufficient statistic for this model.

Can it be said that $Y_i \sim N(\alpha,\beta^2\tau^2+\sigma^2)$ here?
I can't guarantee that it is in the exponential family.
Any approach?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are interested in the MSS for all the unknown parameters $ \theta = ( \alpha, \theta, \beta, \sigma^2 )$. The distribution of $Y$ is indeed normal with mean $\alpha$ and variance $\beta^2 \tau ^ 2 + \sigma^2$.Intuitively you need a vector of $4$ statistics, which should be $T(X) = (\sum X_i, \sum Y_i, \sum X_i^2, \sum Y_i^2)$. For the proof you can use the factorization criteria  where you have a sample of $n$ i.i.d observations (realizations) from a bivariate normal distribution of $(X_i, Y_i)$ where the mean vector is $(\mu_Y, \mu_X) = (0, \alpha)$ and the covariance matrix is

\begin{align}
\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
 \tau ^ 2 && \beta \tau^2 \newline
\beta \tau ^2 && \beta^2 \tau ^ 2 + \sigma^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: But suppose I am not interested in estimating the parameters.So, if I consider $Y_i \sim N(\alpha,\beta^2 \tau^2+\sigma^2)$ then $(\sum Y_i,\sum Y_i^2 )$ is minimal sufficient.

Comment: Sufficient statistic is w.r.t. unknown parameters. There is no meaning talking about MSS without specifying the parameters.