# Normal marginals imply bivariate normal?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, regression

I have a question arising from the answer of this post of mine:
[Minimal sufficient statistic for simple correlated model](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518403/minimal-sufficient-statistic-for-simple-correlated-model/3521384?noredirect=1#comment7242213_3521384)
That suppose $Y \sim N(\alpha,\beta^2 \tau^2 + \sigma^2)$ ,$X \sim N(0,\tau^2)$ and $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ where $Y=\alpha+\beta X+\epsilon$ , how can you say that $(X,Y)$ follows bivariate normal distribution? There are examples that the marginals are normal but still the joint distribution is not bivariate normal.
We cannot directly say that $(X,Y)$ follows bivariate normal right?

Comment: The marginal distributions do not determine the joint distribution and you are right in saying that the jointly distribution need not be normal when there is no additional in formation.

Comment: So suppose if I have to find a minimal sufficient statistic for the above model i.e. for $(\alpha,\beta,\tau^2,\sigma^2)$ then will $(\sum Y_i,\sum Y_i^2)$ do? Or, do I need to find the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$?

Answer (score 2):

[One definition of $(X,Y)$ being bivariate normal is "any linear combination of $X$ and $Y$" is normal.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Equivalent_definitions) In your case where $Y = \alpha + \beta X + \epsilon$ with $X$ and $\epsilon$ independent normal, we have $aX+bY = (a+b\beta)X + b\epsilon + b\alpha$ which is still normal since it is the sum of independent normal random variables and a constant.

Comment: In addition, if $(X,\epsilon)$ are bivariate normal then so too will be  $(X,Y)$.  But otherwise then probably not